# php artisan migrate can not find my database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've created MySQL database named `resume_manager` My DB username is `root` and password is `password` But when I run `php artisan migrate` The error message bellow is showing.

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'resume_manager' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = resume_manager and table_name = migrations)

  at /home/geralt/Music/resume-manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'resume_manager'")
      /home/geralt/Music/resume-manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=resume_manager", "root", "password", [])
      /home/geralt/Music/resume-manager/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

I'm running MySQL on Xampp. I've checked my.cnf file port is set to the default `3306`
I don't know what's going on. By the way I'm using `Linux Mint`.
And I also ran all the commands regarding `cache`

```
          php artisan cache:clear
          php artisan route:cache
          php artisan config:clear
          php artisan view:clear
```

This is my `.env` file setup:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=resume_manager
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be `resume-manager` (hyphen vs. underscore)? I see both in your posting.

Comment: `resume-manager` it's the project directory

Answer (score 0):

From the error it is sure that there is no problem with you port, username and password they all are correct... so just double check `resume_manager` exist or not else;

simple go to your mysql console and create an empty database

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE resume_manager;
```

---

or

you do the same using phpmyadmin too...

if database already exist it will give error else new required db will be created... (there might be some typo issue in your old db name)

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE resume_manager` I ran it on phpmyadmin and it's giving me error. I've checked several times there is no typo

Answer (score 0):

try making new database , if the same problem happened again , you can use this command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we change the `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` in `.env` file, we need to clear the cache:`php artisan config:cache`

After you can run the migrate Artisan command: `php artisan migrate`

Comment: @AkhlakurRahman please check that you have created a database named **resume_manager** in the server database? also restart Apache and MySQL server in XAMPP

Comment: @AkhlakurRahman Try changing the new database name after run `php artisan config:cache` and then run `php artisan migrate` command, Don't forget to backup your old database

Comment: " There are no commands defined in the "config" namespace. "

Answer (score 0):

After you change `.env` file always clear config

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: " There are no commands defined in the "config" namespace. "